# what is use for switching to next column in programs

Tags: java, android, android-api-levels

/t is using for tab /n is using for next line then what is use for next column

Comment: this will be easily find out by google...

Comment: try finding answers by yourselves you will be amazed to know what you can do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Change the return type of your read class to get the data in other activity

2.Make object of your database class and read data from that object Example
YourDBClass db=new YourDBClass();
String[] result=db.read();

Answer (score 0):

```
public void read(View v) {
        Cursor c = dBase.query("employee", null, "id=?", new String[]{ET1.getText().toString()}, null, null, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    c.getInt(0) + "\n" +
                            c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                            c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                            c.getString(3),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        ET1.setText("" + c.getInt(0));
        ET2.setText("" + c.getString(1));
        ET3.setText("" + c.getString(2));
        ET4.setText("" + c.getString(3));

        Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("1", "");
        i.putExtra("2", "");
        i.putExtra("3", "");
        i.putExtra("4", "");
        startActivity(i);

        /*write this Code in another activity after SetContentView();  to display data */

        Log.e("1", getIntent().getStringExtra("1"));
        Log.e("2", getIntent().getStringExtra("2"));
        Log.e("3", getIntent().getStringExtra("3"));
        Log.e("4", getIntent().getStringExtra("4"));
    }
```

Comment: ** in this the application being carshed

Comment: i want a list of data which i have inserted